# set ApplicationPath dynamically

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

How can I set set ApplicationPath dynamically based on uri string from a config file ? 
Are there any alternatives ?

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("some/uri/test")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application 
{  
}
```

Comment: An alternative: don't make it a problem of your Java application / server configuration, but rather setup routes using a tool like nginx. Being a little more specific about why you need to make it configurable can help to know what suggestions will actually be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot set the value of the `@ApplicationPath` dynamically.

However you could try to configure the application path using a `web.xml` deployment descriptor. Instead of hardcoding the `url-pattern`, use [Maven Resource Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to read the value from a configuration file.

---

In Servlet 3.x with JAX-RS 1.1 and later, you can specify the fully qualified name of the class that implements `Application` in the `<servlet-name>`. Note that the `<servlet-class>` element is omitted from the Servlet declaration:

```xml
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.example.ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.example.ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>${application.path}</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

See the [Maven Resource Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) documentation for details on how to configure the value for the `${application.path}` variable.